# Format momentjs datetime stored in mysql (utc format) to Local DateTime

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, datetime, momentjs

I have a column in table called registerdate with type datatime in mysql.

Say right now time is "2015-10-10 06:00:00" local time.

In database I am storing UTC time, so it will be converted to "2015-10-10 00:30:00" as local time is +530 GMT. So correct time is stored in database.

How can I convert registration time to local time when I retrieve it.

This is how I converted before saving datetime to db

```
moment.utc(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

This is what i am trying to convert it back to local time.

```
moment.utc(registerdate, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").local().format("HH:mm:ss")
```

This makes no change to saved date and render the same as stored in db.

Second Approach: It further subtract 5:30 hours instead of adding to it.

```
moment.utc(_obj[i].StartTime).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

Which step I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need to use moment at all. If the date coming from the database is a valid date all you need to do is

```js
var someDate = new Date("2015-10-10 00:30:00");
$("#content").html(someDate.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<div>
```

You will see that this gives you the local time as JS assumes that you gave it local time.

you can add "Z" to the end of the string to force JS to assume the input value as UTC time. When "Z" (Zulu) is tacked on the end of a time, it indicates that that time is UTC http://www.wikiwand.com/en/ISO_8601#/Time_zone_designators

```js
var someDate = new Date("2015-10-10 00:30:00Z");
$("#content").html(someDate.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<div>
```

In case you need to use moment 
instead of  new Date("2015-10-10 00:30:00Z") 
you could do moment("2015-10-10 00:30:00Z")
Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

I don't think using JavaScript it's a good idea for saving a datetime in MySQL. I think is better to use the MySQL function [UTC_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp). For example:

```
INSERT INTO `ITEMS` (`name`, `date_add`) VALUES ('item name', UTC_TIMESTAMP());
```

Now, when you retrieve the UTC datetime from MySQL, you can convert it to a Moment object like this:

```
var utc = moment.utc(MYSQL_DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
var local = utc.local();
// var local = moment.utc(MYSQL_DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').local();
console.log( local.format("HH:mm:ss") );   // 15:54:31
console.log( local.fromNow() );            // a minute ago
```

I don't see anything wrong in your code. Maybe it's something in the application side (PHP?).

Another thing. Using the method utc() without parameters is the same as calling utc(new Date()). So you can simply use this in your convertion to MySQL datetime:

```
//moment.utc(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
moment.utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

Note: excuse my bad English.